# undefined method `[]' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting `undefined method [] for true:TrueClass` error while running the rake task in acts_as_recommendable plugin. The error points to the following line.

```
  items = options[:on_class].find(:all).collect(&:id)
```

Can someone please tell what am i doing incorrectly.

Comment: it looks to me like you're doing something like `key = true` where you mean to do `key => true`

Comment: yeah, obviously 'options' is not a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`options` is probably defined as `true`. We can't really know why without more information.